# How To Replace The Same Picture in Multiple Word Files

Tags: microsoft-word, updates, hyperlink, links, pictures

I am using Word for Microsoft 365 and it is currently version 16.40.

I have a logo that is updated once a year. The same logo is in 100+ documents. Ideally I would like to have all the logos in the Word documents update as soon as I replace the old file on my local drive with the new logo with the same filename.

I have read about how to do this [a few different ways](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/replacement-of-company-logo-image-in-multiple-word/23fe1e9c-03ae-4638-ad39-0b30e134e717) with older versions of Word and the only relevant [post about my question on this site was asked 11 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/38870/in-microsoft-word-how-can-i-link-to-an-image-from-the-web-which-updates) (as far as I know).

Is there a current way to auto-update pictures in multiple word documents just by changing the original picture?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way for that as stated. However, if all the documents come from the same template (likely), and are stored with the same filename (e.g. `image001.png`) inside the resulting docx (.docx is a zip-based format), you could use a zip utility (like `zip`) to replace that image with the new one (assuming old and new images have the same dimensions).

As you can see, there are a lot of caveats there. Most likely, even if having a common ancestor, the file name will vary, your users will have removed the logo and added it again, etc.

Thus, rather than blindly changing an image with a set name, I would use a more robust script that checked all the images inside the zip (Word File), and replaced the instances of an image given as old with the one provided as new.

Do note that if the old and new images don't have the same dimensions, results will probably be "funny". Plus obviously won't work if next year rather than one logo you need to have two or three of them there.